# Spring authentication is working only for first api

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

When I'm hitting the first API through postman it is asking the user/password but after 1st API it is working without auth as well

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/altitude/bro/code").hasRole(Constants.USER)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
```

Comment: No it isn't. After a succesfull authentication the browser will automatically include the basic authentication header, and thus you don't need to re-authenticate each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-authenticate, either remove the cookies or go to the settings of Postman and let it not re-use the cookies.